# Equality of nested radicals with different operations

Tags: recreational-mathematics, self-learning, nested-radicals

I was playing around on Maple with some nested radicals and I notices that 
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}}=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\cdots}}}}=2$$
I thought my mind was playing tricks on me so I did the algebra; I let $$x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}}$$  Then $x^2=2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}}$, and thus
$$x^2=2+x$$
Solving for $x$, $x=-1,$ or $2$, so $x=2$.
Then I did it for the multiplied nested radical.  Again, I let 
$$x=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\cdots}}}}$$
Then $x^2=2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\cdots}}}}$, and thus
$$x^2=2x$$
Solving for $x$, $x=0,2$, so $x=2$
So naturally I wondered if this could happen with any other number other than 2.  It did not work with 3, or 4 (i figured that was the case) so again, I let algebra take over.  I replaced $2$ with $a$ and I said that a solution would be where 
$$a+x=ax$$
But this is not the correct approach.  Then I thought that I needed to solve the summed radical first using the quadratic formula, so
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4a}}{2} $$
And then the multiplied radical
$$x=0, x=a$$
So plugging in $a$ for $x$ in the first equation gives  $a=2$.  Thus the only number that satisfies this equality is $a=2$.

Now
(A)  is this correct?
(B)  are there any more interesting results such as this perhaps with multiple variables or other operations involved?

Comment: Try $y=(\sqrt2)^y$.

Comment: Here's another beauty that you can check out: $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\cdots}}}$$

Comment: I noticed the first one was the golden ratio.  Awesome....